# how to receive ussd message as a server by an android / iphone / windows phone?

Tags: android, iphone, ussd

I'm planning to develop a server application that wait ussd requests and respond it.

Usually ussd recipient is like *100# but I'm just wondering is it possible to send request to ordinary cell phone?

e.g. my number is +63-927-111-2222, how can I send ussd request to this phone? is it *639271112222# or *9271112222# ?

And have you seen applications or code of android/iphone/windows phone that makes it possible?

Comment: You can't send a USSD request TO a phone, only FROM a phone.

Comment: So, career company is the only one to receive request FROM a phone?

Comment: it's impossible to send USSD request FROM a phone TO a phone?